# CSS Media Queries not kicking in when there supposed to

Tags: css, webkit, media-queries

Hi Guys (& Girls of course)

I'm having a major problem with webkit and media queries. Basically they are only kicking in around 15-30px after they should.

When I load the page with Javascript enabled I can see from the console the correct device width and this corresponds with the array of extensions that I've thrown at it.

When I disable javascript I get the same result so obviously it isn't my javascript or any plugins that are throwing things out.

In the dev tools I can watch the inspector tab and the relevant media queries don't kick in until after they are supposed to and you can see the the resolution they have kicked in don't match the media queries themselves.

Any help would be much appreciated on this one as I'm now not really able to come up with any other suggestions.

If there is any information that I can give you  that will help you to help me please let me know (I'm restricted in what screenshots I can provide due to non-disclosure).

Thanks in advance & here's hoping :-)
John

Comment: I've been having the very same problem and not found a solution yet. I thought it might be something to do with the vertical scrollbar being included in some calculations and not in others (i.e. difference between screen width calculated by CSS, javascript, firebug etc.)

Comment: Any difference between a page without scrollbar and one long enough to have one? The scrollbar has a width...

Answer (score 2):

After sharing my question on Twitter I was sent this link which has fixes

http://mattstow.com/your-media-queries-are-wrong-fix-them-with-viewport-genie-and-mqgenie.html

It basically says that webkit doesn't take into account the scrollbars when applying media queries and that would (to me) explain the correct space that the media queries are off by. I hope that others find this answer useful as I couldn't find any information by searching Google. Obviously now that I am able to narrow down the search I would probably be able to to find the answer on there.

Comment: I believe the same issues applies to FF, anyway once you sync it, it will be synced cross browser

Answer (score 1):

Check the difference between the browser width and the viewport width. It's the latter you want to design for with mobiles, tablets etc.

Comment: Thanks, it was the viewport/point measurement I was using butthe problem lies (I have just discovered) in the scrollbars

Answer (score 1):

The scrollbar is the cause of this, the calculated width from js and the width you define in media query are not the same due to scrollbar (I think in some browsers they are the same but not all).

You need to sync the width so that js and media query is the same. If you want to go with media query width then you probably need an element to check for that changes with the css. If you wanna go with js width then you can easily add a class to the body and target your media query with that class. I am sure there are other ways of syncing as well.

Comment: Thanks and spot on (see my above answer). It is something that had never occurred to me and it's quite unbelievable it isn't mentioned in  any of the media query tutorials I've read in the past (admittedly a while ago).

Thanks again, my answer has a fix from a site other than mine for future reference.